# Where can one get token fee calculations instead of it keep eating up my ETH for gas for guessing the gas limit?

Tags: transactions, gas, metamask, gas-limit, failed-transaction

This is kind of ridiculous, every time I try to send out tokens to another address from metamask, it fails. I doubled my GAS limit from 20K to 70K and it still fails. Where can one even find the appropriate GAS limit setting? Every time it fails it eats up my eth which is not cheap for sending tokens at .20-.50 USD.

Answer (score 1):

A transfer for a simple ERC20 token used 51,574 gas.  MetaMask set the gas limit at 54,861 gas.
Though the required gas will depend on how the ERC20 contract was implemented.
You can always have a look on Etherscan for the transaction fees for previous transfers of the ERC20 token.

Gas prices are 5 gwei for standard speed according to https://ethgasstation.info/